# Faker symbol cannot be resolved in intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver

I'm using   Faker faker = new faker(); code and GitHub javafaker version 0.12.
I've tried changing version, making src to source root but nothing has worked and I get "Can not resolve symbol faker" error.

No firewall blocking either.

How do I fix this?

I'm on windows 10 using intellij for maven project.

Comment: Looks like you are not able to download the javafaker-0.12.jar from repository, are you behind the poxy ? What is you pom looks like ?

Comment: I'm not behind any proxy.<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
        <version>0.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependencies>
</project>

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks @ravthiru for your insight. I just went on GitHub site and copied the dependency from there. Now it works.

Comment: thats simplest solution to keep going